# @api.onchange called from xml-rpc

Tags: odoo

I created a function f. e.

```py
@api.onchange('zip')
def onchange_zip(self):
   self.name = "%s %s" % (self.name, self.zip)
```

It works perfectly when I change the zip field by interface. But when I do it by xml-rpc or any other api it is not triggered. Is it possible to solve it different than overriding write, create methods?

Answer (score 1):

`@api.onchage` is meant to be used to update something on the fly, for example changing something on field in the web interface in `edit` mode and immediately update the effect on other field. Whenever you change the same field value by other mean, for example from python code, or odoo shell, or in this example `xmlrpc` protocol, there is no call made to the `@onchange` function. There are number of ways to fix this, you can use `compute` function instead of `@onchange`, compute function is triggered from `orm` level, whenever any change is detected in the records field mentioned by `@api.depends` decorator. Or simply, you can just make a call to the `@onchange` method manually whenever you are changing the value in field.